# create restful apis with Event driven architecture node js?

Tags: node.js, event-driven

Hi I'm a newbie in `nodejs` as far as I'm concerned `nodejs` is `event-driven` which is a powerful feature in it.

I have been learning `nodejs` from last few days and try to build restful apis in it with `mongodb`, but I'm not able to use its `event-driven` architecture in apis below is my sudo code

```
//routes

   app.get('/someUrl', SomeClass.executeSomeController);


//controller

  class SomeClass {
    async executeSomeController(req, res){
       let response = awaitSomeHelper.executeQueryAndBusinessLogic(req.body);
       res.send(response)
  }

}
```

As per my understanding I have written normal code as I used to write using `Ror` or `PHP` The only difference I found that the `controller` is running `asynchronous` which does not happens in `Ror` or `Php`.

How can I use `event-driven` architecture to build  restful apis

Answer (score 3):

Hope I can cover your question. Basically in some cases 'event-driven architecture' term can be explained differently. In one case it's a basic core NodeJS flow that explains all the async functions. In another case, the root of the question can be related to events, event emitter etc.

But the main idea that you have to wait for all the asynchronous actions. In order to avoid thread blocking it goes further and handles the rest of your code without waiting for heavy requests. And there we have to know how to handle this async functionality.

## Basic Async Flow

As I understand, you've got questions related to async operations in NodeJS. That's a root of the technology - all the heavy operations will be handled asynchronously. It's all about V8 and Event Loop.

So in order to work with asynchronous operations, you may use callback functions, promises or async-await syntax.

**Callback Functions**

```
function asyncFunction(params, callback) {
  //do async stuff
  callback(err, result);
}

function callbackFunction(err, result) {

}

asyncFunction(params, callbackFunction);
```

**Promises**

```
promiseFunction()
  .then(anotherPromiseFunction)
  .then((result) => {
    //handle result
  })
  .catch((err) => {
    //handle error
  });
```

**async-await**

```
function anotherAsyncFunction() {
  //do async stuff
}

const asycnFunction = async (params) => {
  const result = await anotherAsyncFunction();
  return result;
};
```

## Events/Event Emitter

```
const fs = require('fs');

const filePath = './path/to/your/file';
const stream = fs.createReadStream(filePath);

stream.on('data', (data) => {
  //do something
});

stream.on('end', () => {
  //do something;
});

stream.on('error', (err) => {
  //do something;
});
```

You may use these methods depends on the situation and your needs. I recommend skipping callback functions as we have modern ways to work in async flow (promises and async-await). By the way, 'async-await' returns promises as well.

Here is the example of a simple Express JS Server (pretty old syntax), but still valid. Please feel free to check and write questions:

https://github.com/roman-sachenko/express-entity-based

Here is a list of articles I'd recommend you:

https://blog.risingstack.com/node-js-at-scale-understanding-node-js-event-loop/
https://blog.risingstack.com/mastering-async-await-in-nodejs/